# asp.net using mvc 3 sending feedback via email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with sending feedback through email.. sending feedback is good i can receive the feedbacks. but i cant see who is the sender... it always indicate that the email is being sent by myself also... help pls.

heres my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Feedback()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Feedback(string email, string subject, string body)
{
    try
    {
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
        WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
        WebMail.UserName = "aaaa@gmail.com";
        WebMail.From = email;
        WebMail.Password = "12345";
        WebMail.Send("aaaa@gmail.com",subject,body,email);

        return RedirectToAction("FeedbackSent");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ex.ToString());
    }

    return View();
}

public ActionResult FeedbackSent()
{
    return View();
}
```

tnx for those who can help.... the email and password indicate are not legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it always indicate that the email is being sent by myself

That's normal. You cannot send an email on behalf of someone else. You could include a FirstName, LastName and Email fields in the feedback form asking the users to fill them. And if the users are kind enough to fill this information you could include it in the body of the email that is being sent.

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's what you could do. Use the email field to include the information in the body:

```
WebMail.Send(
    "aaaa@gmail.com",
    subject,
    string.Format("{0} wrote the following feedback: {1}", email, body),
    email
);
```

Comment: hmn... can you pls provide me with codes? im new in asp.net mvc... and i cant find a solid answers in the net.. thanks... :D

Comment: Add a parameter called `email` to your `Feedback` HttpPost controller action. And then add it to the body of the email. You will need a corresponding field called email on your form in the view.

Comment: i already edit my code above and put my view... im still confuse..can you ellaborate your question in codes?thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how you could compose the body of the email to include the sender email in it.

Comment: sir.... how can i add a function that everytime a email was send to me  a email with a letter is being send ryt away after the sender sends its feedback.. tnx...